# Can not show more than one text label in a table without problems

Tags: swift

I'm using the following code on swift to try to get it to show more than one text label, but for some reason on the table it only shows the operating system label.

It's probably something pretty obvious and I'm just dumb/blind, but I can't find it for the life of me. Thanks.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
               cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, 
                                                reuseIdentifier: "Default")

    cell.textLabel?.text = servInfo.servers[indexPath.row].name
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Username: " + servInfo.servers[indexPath.row].username
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Password: " + servInfo.servers[indexPath.row].password
    cell.textLabel?.text = "IPv4 Address" + servInfo.servers[indexPath.row].ipv4
    cell.textLabel?.text = "IPv6 Address" + servInfo.servers[indexPath.row].ipv6
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Protocol:" + servInfo.servers[indexPath.row].pcal
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Operating System: " + servInfo.servers[indexPath.row].os
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = servInfo.servers[indexPath.row].addi

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not concatenating the string.
you are erasing content of cell.textLabel and writing a new text in every line.

use string concatenation.

**use this:**

cell.textLabel.text += ("blabla" + "\n");

cell.textLabel.text += ("blabla" + "\n");

**or use this:**

cell.textLabel.text = cell.textLabel.text + ("blabla" + "\n");

cell.textLabel.text = cell.textLabel.text + ("blabla" + "\n");

**instead of this:**

cell.textLabel.text = "blabla";

cell.textLabel.text = "blabla";

Answer (score 0):

additional to the other answers it's less expensive – and more descriptive – to compose the whole string in a variable and then set the label.
I added also a couple of line breaks

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
  cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
      reuseIdentifier: "Default")

    let server = servInfo.servers[indexPath.row]
    var text = server.name
    text += "\nUsername: " + server.username
    text += "\nPassword: " + server.password
    text += "\nIPv4 Address" + server.ipv4
    text += "\nIPv6 Address" + server.ipv6
    text += "\nProtocol:" + server.pcal
    text += "\nOperating System: " + server.os

    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = server.addi

    return cell
}
```